# c++ force std::cout flush (print to screen)

Tags: c++, cout, flush

I have code such as the following:

```
std::cout << "Beginning computations..."; // output 1
computations();
std::cout << " done!\n";                  // output 2
```

The problem, however, is that often output #1 and output #2 appear (virtually) simultaneously.  That is, often output #1 does not get printed to the screen until after `computations()` returns.  Since the entire purpose of output #1 is to indicate that something is going on in the background (and thus to encourage patience from the user), this problem is not good.

Is there any way to force the `std::cout` buffer to get printed before the `computations()` call?  Alternatively, is there some other way (using something other than `std::cout`) to print to standard out that would fix this problem?

Comment: I hear `std::endl` is pretty popular for this kinda thing...

Comment: @ebyrob But this will end the line, and if he wants to continue printing on the same line after the computation, he needs to manually flush.

Comment: @leemes that's very true.  In that case he can either use `fprintf()`, `std::flush` (as below), or modify his version of `cout` to automatically flush at the end of each line of code... I had a SO thread for that last one but seem to have lost it.

Comment: @synaptik what you facing I am not facing. it's working fine. I just made `computation` function with one `cout` line. but it is printing that `"Beginning computations..."` before calling the function. but I need to find at which particular case buffer will not free.

Comment: Am using gcc compiler. Added "-static" flag and it worked. See [this so ans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58789865/1977871)

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Just insert [`std::flush`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/flush):

```
std::cout << "Beginning computations..." << std::flush;
```

Also note that inserting [`std::endl`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl) will also flush after writing a newline.

Comment: @user1810087 Sorry, I edited it in, but pretty quickly. I think it was before you answered.

Comment: I enjoyed the comments :D

Comment: @JosephMansfield but in my case it is not happening means there is no need to use of `std::flush`. can you give a case where buffer is not full so `cout` is not printing.

Answer (score 9):

In addition to Joseph Mansfield answer, [std::endl](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl) does the flush too (besides a new line).

> Inserts a endline character into the output sequence os and flushes it as if by calling os.put(os.widen('\n')) followed by os.flush().