# Method is being called on class with uninitialized attributes despite constructors

Tags: c++, debugging

**Premise:** suppose I have a rectangular subset of 2D space and a collection of points, all with different `x`-values, in this subset. In the interest of the optimization of an algorithm as yet unwritten, I want to split my box into cells according to the following process: I halve my rectangle into 2 equal parts along the `x`-axis. Then I repeatedly halve each sub-rectangle until every cell contains either 1 point or none at all.[image: Example]

In this illustration the vertical lines represent the “halving process” and the lines are ordered by darkness (darker is newer).

First I’ll define two basic classes:

```
class Point{
    private:
        double x;
        double y;
    public:
        // [...]
        // the relevant constructor and getter
        // overloaded operators +, -, * for vector calculations
};

class Box{
    private:
        Point bottom_left_point;
        double width;
        double height;
    public:
        Box(Point my_point, double my_x, double my_y) : // constructor
            bottom_left_point(my_point), width(my_x), height(my_y){}

        bool contains(const Point& p); // returns true iff the box contains p in the geometric sense
        Box halve(bool b) const; // takes a boolean as input and returns the left half-rectangle for false, and the right half-rectangle for true
};
```

Now to implement the “halving algorithm” I’ll need a binary tree-like structure. Each node will represent a sub-cell of the rectangle (with the root node representing the total rectangle). A node may have two children, in which case the children represent its left and right halves. A node may also have a pointer to a particle which exists in the cell. The ultimate idea will be to start with an empty tree and insert the points in, one by one using a method `insert(Point* to_be_inserted)`.

So I’ll define the following recursive class, whose `private` attributes are rather self-explanatory:

```
class Node;

class Node{
    private:
        enum node_type{ INT, EXT, EMPTY };

        node_type type;
        // type == INT means that it is an interior node, i.e. has children
        // type == EXT means that it is an exterior node, i.e. has no children but contains a point
        // type == EMPTY means that it has no children and no point

        std::array<Node*,2> children;
        Box domain; // the geometric region which is being represented
        Point* tenant; // address of the particle that exists in this cell (if one such exists)

    public:
        Node(Box my_domain) :
            type(EMPTY), children({nullptr}), domain(my_domain){}
        //
        // to be continued...
```

The first order of business is to define a `subdivide()` method which endows my node with two children:

```
void Node::subdivide(void){
    type = INT;
    children[0] = new Node(domain.halve(false));
    children[1] = new Node(domain.halve(true));
}
```

Now everything is in place to write the crux of this whole affair, the `insert` method. Since it will be written recursively, the easiest solution is to have a boolean return type which tells us if the insertion was a success or failure. With this in mind, here’s the code:

```
bool Node::insert(Point* to_be_inserted){
    if(not domain.contains(*to_be_inserted)) return false;
    switch(type){
        case INT:{
            for(Node* child : children) if(child->insert(to_be_inserted)) return true;
            return false;
        }
        case EXT:{
            subdivide();

            for(Node* child : children) if(child->insert(to_be_inserted)) break;
            tenant = nullptr;

            for(Node* child : children) if(child->insert(to_be_inserted)) return true;
            break;
        }
        case EMPTY:{    
            type = EXT;
            tenant = to_be_inserted;
            return true;
        }
    }
    throw 1; // this line should not, in, theory ever be reached
}
```

(Note that, for the sake of abstraction and generality, I have used `for` loops on the array `children` when I could have simply written out the two cases.)

**Explanation:**

- First we check if `to_be_inserted` is in the geometric region represented by `this`. If not, return `false`.
- If `this` is an internal node, we pass the point on to the each child until it is successfully inserted.
- If `this` is an external node, that means that we have to split the node in two in order to be able to properly isolate `to_be_inserted` from the point that currently lives in the node.

  - First we call `multiply()`.
  - Then we attempt to `insert` the current tenant into one of the children (please excuse how obscene this sounds, I assure you that it’s unintentional).
  - Once that is done, we do the same with `to_be_inserted` and return the result. (Note that *a priori* the insertion would be a success at this point because of the preliminary call to `box::contains`.
- Finally, if `this` is an `EMPTY` node, we simply have to assign `tenant` to `*to_be_inserted` and change `type` to `EXT` and we’re done.

Ok, so let's try it out with a simple `main`:

```
int main(void){
    Box my_box(ORIGIN, 1.0, 1.0); // rectangle of vertices (0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)
    Node tree(box); // initializes an empty tree representing the region of my_box
    Point p(0.1, 0.1);
    Point q(0.6, 0.7);
    tree.insert(&p);
    tree.insert(&q);

    return 0;
}
```

This compiles, but upon running the exception at the bottom of `insert` is thrown after a few calls. How is this possible, given that at no point a `Node` is constructed without a `type` value?

**Edit:** I have noticed, as well as this one, several possible errors which may also occur with small changes in the code:

- An inexplicable call to `nullptr->insert(something)`
- A call to `insert` by the address `0x0000000000000018` which doesn't point to an initialized `Node`.

---

The entirety of the code, including a `makefile` with the relevant debugging flags, can be found at https://github.com/raphael-vock/phantom-call.

Comment: What's the full stack trace of the fault?  From a quick look at your code, you're passing in the address of local, stack objects to your `tree.insert()` method.  Then `main()` returns, and all the local stack object destructors get called when the local stack objects go out of scope.  That's has a [nasty code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).

Comment: @Andrew,  I understand what you mean but the main simply serves to test the functioning of the code. Does this explain what happens before the main returns?

Comment: Look at `main`.  You declare a `tree`, then declare two local variables `p` and `q`.  On the return of `main`, objects/variables are destroyed in the reverse order of their declarations.  So `q` and `p` go up in smoke, then `tree`.  But what about the pointers `tree` stored i.e. (`p` and `q`)?  They're now gone.  Whether this is the reason for the error, I don't know, but as the first comment suggested, this is an issue.

Comment: Put some `cerr` debug code to generate output in your `Point` and `Node` destructors.  Include the value of `this` in what you print.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Thanks, just tried that. Nothing was printed (at least not before the exception was thrown). This time the stop reason was because of a `nullptr->insert(something)` call which I don't understand at all.

Comment: That would mean the exception happens before `main()` returns.  Keep adding debug output until you can identify the exact line?  (You did use `cerr` and not `cout`, right?  `cout` can be buffered.  Or if you do use `cout`, make sure you flush it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22026751/c-force-stdcout-flush-print-to-screen)

Comment: @RaphaelVock  `throw 1; // this line should not, in, theory ever be reached` -- Why not?  Did you test this?  How are you sure those loops in the case statements return `true`?  I think your assumptions are wrong, and this is just a bug (nothing to do with uninitialized classes, from the surface).  If that line is invoked, that is a scenario for the unhandled exception.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Yes I used `cerr`, nothing. Same goes if I try throwing an exception in the destructors (very bad form, I know).

Comment: `if(not domain.contains(*to_be_inserted)) return false;` -- One thing you really should do to help debugging -- break up this into two separate lines.  More than likely, the return value is always `false`, and you're not realizing it.

Comment: I took your code and made a Visual Studio project.  Indeed, that return value is always `false` (never `true`), thus the `throw 1` line is invoked.