# How to fix the random character outputs in C++?

Tags: c++

When I get string input by using char arrays and I cycle through them with a for loop, my code always has random character outputs that should not be there.

I have tried debugging my code, by checking the output at various stages, but I can't find the reason for what is happening.

```
    int k, s, counter = 0;
    char word[21];

    std::cin>>k;
    std::cin.getline(word,21);
    for (int i = 0; word[i] != ' '; i++)
    {
        s = 3*(i + 1) + k;
        std::cout<<s;
        for (int k = 0; k < s; k++)
        {
            word[i]--;
            if (word[i] < 'A')
               word[i] = 'Z';
        }
    std::cout<<word[i];
    }
```

When I type in 3 to get the value of k, I already get the output "URORIFCFWOQNJCEBFVSPMJNKD" when I should not get any output.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Concerning your issue, please extract a [mcve]. Without that, your question is considered off-topic unfortunately, even though the problem itself may well be on-topic.

Comment: Does the input string have a space? If not `for (int i = 0; word[i] != ' '; i++)` will cause a problem.

Comment: 1) Seems that it's, at least, relevant to [Why does std::getline() skip input after a formatted extraction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction), if it's not duplicate. 2) Why are you using `char` arrays to read strings, instead of `std::string`?

Comment: What is that code supposed to do? There are many odd things going on in it.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp since the size of the string the user input varies, I thought I would use the word[i] != ' ' to stop the for loop when it encounters a space in the char array.

Comment: @TedLyngmo the code is supposed to be for this question: https://dmoj.ca/problem/ccc12j4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the buffer is not flushed before using `getline`.
Because of that when you hit enter after entering a number, that enter (character '\n') is passed to `getline()`, and at that point getline ends his work by leaving the `word` empty.

The solution to this is simple:  Flush the buffer before getline.

Here is the complete solution:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int k, s, counter = 0;
    char word[21];

    std::cin>>k;

    // Clear the buffer
    std::cin.clear();
    while (std::cin.get() != '\n') 
    {
        continue;
    }

    std::cin.getline(word,21);

    std::cout<<"TEST>"<<word<<"<TEST"<<std::endl<<std::flush;

    for (int i = 0; word[i] != ' '; i++)
    {
        s = 3*(i + 1) + k;
        std::cout<<s;
        for (int k = 0; k < s; k++)
        {
            word[i]--;
            if (word[i] < 'A')
               word[i] = 'Z';
        }

        // Use std::flush to forcefully print current output.
        std::cout<<word[i]<<std::flush;
    }
}
```

Notes:

- I've used the buffer clearing mechanism described [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31872811/5935112). You might use another, but the idea is the same
- If you comment the 4 lines of that buffer clearing part, you'll notice that as soon as you type "3" and hit enter, you see an output like `"TEST><TEST"` which means that the `word` inside it, is empty.
- Consider using `std::flush` while using cout if you want forcefully print the output before the for cycle ends.

Comment: The flushing works, thanks, but what does the std::flush at the end do? Although you said it forcefully prints the output, I don't see a difference with and without the std::flush

Comment: When you try to print something on the screen using methods like cout, it doesn't immidiately get printed as it might be time-consuming. So, it gets buffered and printed only from time to time. For example, if you have a cout in a for loop, you might notice that every time you cout something from that loop, it's not immidiately is printed on screen. You might use std::flush to force all that buffered stuff to be printed. Here is some example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38112106/5935112 and slightly more details https://stackoverflow.com/q/22026751/5935112

Answer (score 0):

`std::cin >> k;` is reading an integer only. It does *not* read the trailing line break. The [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2) of the `>>` operator says

> The extraction stops if one of the following conditions are met:
>
> - a whitespace character [...] is found. The whitespace character is not extracted.

As [Just Shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5935112/just-shadow) pointed out this line break is causing the `getline()` call to return an empty string.

You can ignore any number of line breaks by calling

```
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

BTW: Looking at your outer `for` loop I would be concerned that you might read beyond the end of `word` if the string doesn't contain any whitespaces. The following solution fixes that as well:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main() {
    int k, s, counter = 0;
    char word[21];

    std::cin >> k;
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    std::cin.getline(word, 21);
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(word) && word[i] != ' '; i++)
    {
        s = 3 * (i + 1) + k;
        std::cout<<s;
        for (int k = 0; k < s; k++)
        {
            word[i]--;
            if (word[i] < 'A')
               word[i] = 'Z';
        }
        std::cout << word[i];
    }
}
```