# Is there any errors in my code? C++ code using BGI graphics not working for me

Tags: c++, bgi

```
// Program to implement 2D transformations on a rectangle.
// (1) Translation (2) Rotation (3) Scaling.

#include<iostream.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<graphics.h>
#include<math.h>

void main()
{
   clrscr();
   int tx,ty,c,t,i,j,k,sx,sy,x1,x2,y1,y2;
   float tx1;
   int gd = DETECT, gm;
   initgraph(&gd, &gm,"C:\\TC\\BGI");
   x1 = y2 = 100;
   x2 = y1 = 150;
   rectangle(x1,y1,x2,y2);

   cout<<"Enter any one transformation:\n1:Translation \n2:Rotation \n3:Scaling  ";
   cout<<"\nSelected: ";
   cin>>c;
switch(c)
{
    case 1:
        cout<<"Enter tx & ty :";
        cin>>tx>>ty;
        rectangle(x1+tx, y1+ty, x2+tx, y2+ty);
        break;

    case 2 :
        int xx1, yy1, xx2, yy2, xx3, yy3, xx4, yy4;
        int ax1, ay1, ax2, ay2, ax3, ay3, ax4, ay4;
        int refx, refy;
        cout<<"Enter an angle for rotation: ";
        cin>>tx1;
        tx1=tx1*(3.14/180);

        refx = refy = 100;

        xx1 = yy1 = yy2 = xx4 = 100;
        xx2 = xx3 = yy3 = yy4 = 150;

        ax1 = refy +(xx1-refx)* cos(tx1)-(yy1-refy)*sin(tx1);
        ay1 = refy +(xx1-refx)* sin(tx1)+(yy1-refy)*cos(tx1);

        ax2 = refy +(xx2-refx)* cos(tx1)-(yy2-refy)*sin(tx1);
        ay2 = refy +(xx2-refx)* sin(tx1)+(yy2-refy)*cos(tx1);

        ax3 = refy +(xx3-refx)* cos(tx1)-(yy3-refy)*sin(tx1);
        ay3 = refy +(xx3-refx)* sin(tx1)+(yy3-refy)*cos(tx1);

        ax4 = refy +(xx4-refx)* cos(tx1)-(yy4-refy)*sin(tx1);
        ay4 = refy +(xx4-refx)* sin(tx1)+(yy4-refy)*cos(tx1);

        line(ax1,ay1, ax2, ay2);
        line(ax2,ay2, ax3, ay3);
        line(ax3,ay3, ax4, ay4);
        line(ax4,ay4, ax1, ay1);
        break;

    case 3 :
       cout<<"Enter sx & sy: ";
       cin>>sx>>sy;
       rectangle(x1*sx, y1*sy, x2*sx, y2*sy);
       break;

    default :
        cout<<"Error! Enter a valid choice";
   }
   getch();
   closegraph();
}
```

Using BGI graphics.h library implementing in C++. I know it's very ancient but I need it for a school project. Apparently not working for me in IDE, I have all libraries installed. It just does not show any output only a black screen.
A program to implement 2D transformations
(i) Scaling (ii) Rotation

Comment: not any output? Also not from the `cout`s ?

Comment: 1985 called...! This technology has been obsolete for roughly twice as long as you've been alive. :)

Comment: @idclev463035818 No. Just a black screen after compiling. Does it have errors linking with BGI libraries?

Comment: Did you actually run the program? Just compiling it isn't enough.

Comment: ^^ that and what do you get if you remove everything but the `cout`s ? Do you still get no output?

Comment: Yes, I am using Codeblocks. Hit build and run button, no errors. Just a blank screen on .exe window.

Comment: How did you manage to get a compiler old enough to need `<iostream.h>` to run on CodeBlocks? o.O

Comment: Ha! I am not sure but it must on gnu gcc compiler. People in my school worked getting it to work on codeblocks so I don't know much.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Does the c++ code look fine to you or is a program with code? If not program must be in the BGI libraries as there always issues with it.

Comment: I wrote an answer 45 minutes ago; you can find it below.

Comment: You need an old version (perhaps 15 years old) of mingw for this to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to guess at the answer to this, since the 1980s technology you're using has been obsolete for many years (and predates even the earliest standard by more than a decade), but if Turbo C++ has `flush` then [you're going to need it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22026751/4386278). Your console output may be buffered until after the user submits input.